# How can I replace a substring with a link?

Tags: php, string, replace, substring

I have a string in text from position 6 to 11 and I want to replace it with an HTML link

How can I do it?

```
$text = 'hello world this is my question , plz help';
$position_from = 15;
$position_to = 20;
$link = 'http://google.com';
```

I need a function that gives me this:

```
$text = 'hello <a href="http://google.com">world</a> this is my question , plz help';
```

Comment: See [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

Comment: you want to replace the `word` with a link? or `<link>word</link>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace a substring with a modified version of the same substring, first calculate the length of the substring to be replaced, by subtracting the start position from the end position.

```
$len = $to - $from;
```

Then you can make the replacement using `substr` and `substr_replace`:

```
$link = '<a href="http://google.com">' . substr($text, $from, $len) . '</a>';
$text = substr_replace($text, $link, $from, $len);
```

or replace using a regular expression with `preg_replace`.

```
$pattern = "/(?<=^.{{$from}})(.{{$len}})/";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="http://www.google.com">$1</a>', $text);
```

For multi-byte safe operation, since there is not `mb_substr_replace`, you can just use `mb_substr` repeatedly:

```
$text = mb_substr($text, 0, $from)
        . "<a href='$url'>" . mb_substr($text, $from, $len) . '</a>'
        . mb_substr($text, $to);
```

Comment: Good call. I didn't consider that the *original* word should *dynamically* persist to the new string.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that made the question a bit more interesting.

Comment: thanks  ! and Im using mb_substr instead of substr becouse persian language... but there is no mb_substr_replace ! how to do it for utf8?

Comment: @MiLaDTNT I edited the answer to show one way to do it using only `mb_substr`.